# DNS setting for openVPN for using remote desktop

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have this error when make mac OSX remote desktop connect via VPN(by openVPN) to remote desktop server(windows)

```
mac OSX(local) -> openVPN(on rent VPS service) -> Windows10
```

error is here below

```
An error occurred while communicating with the Remote Desktop Gateway. If this keeps happening, contact your network administrator for assistance.

Error code: 0x3000008
```

I can use internet via this VPN without problems.

I googled around and guessing this might be relevant with DNS.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251486815

(I should not use google dns?? but why?)

my `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf` is like this below.

Does anyone have any hint?

```
local 153.126.111.11
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Comment: 10.8.x.x is not directly accessible over the 'net. It's a private IP. DNS has nothing to do with this, as you're not dealing with canonical names but distinct [& probably unreachable] IP addresses. If the 'public' IP address of the far node *is* actually 10.x.x.x then you're probably dealing with CGNAT, which may make this impossible.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your comment,my `VPN` server's public address is `153.126.111.11` and currently I can use internet via `VPN`.  However, `server` setting is wrongly pointing private IP?? How can I fix this??

Comment: My mac OSX is not in local network with `VPN` server. it is on rental VPS, and My mac OSX is connecting via internet.

Comment: @whitebear 1) where is the windows machine located, in the same VPS as your vpn server? 2) What are the (local) IP addresses of your Mac and Windows machines? and 3) Are you connecting via IP or host name in RDP?

Comment: 1) windows machine is different VPN not with local mac, not with linux. 2) my local mac ip is 10.68.150.134  but it often changed and I have only domain name for windows(srmterminal.sample.co.jp) 3) connecting with host name srmterminal.sample.co.jp